# XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: c#

XML Parsing Error: no element found

Line Number 1, Column 1:

I want to download a Excel file. I wrote the data in a html table format and appending to the response. The code is following :

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
Response.Write(str);
Response.End();
```

Comment: is it as simple as the filename is blank?

Comment: NO. I have given file name as somefilename.xls

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Response.AddHeader to Response.AppendHeader.

Also add the following lines.

Response.AppendHeader ("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString ());
Response.WriteFile(downloadFilename);
Response.Flush ();
Response.End ();

I have some code that does exactly what you are asking for and these are the only differences...